# I'm on Linux and [application] isn't outputting any sound!!! I have my speakers connected, [other application] works fine, but not this one

Tags: linux, audio, pulse-audio

HELP ME! There's no sound from [application], but [other application] is fine! My volume is up, and it worked before, but it's broken now! (This phrasing is satire, essentially if you're experiencing inexplicable audio cutouts from some applications than this applies to you)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pavucontrol`. It's an application available on most distro package archives that allows you to individually monitor and configure the volume of applications. No sound? Chances are that application is, for some reason, muted. `pavucontrol` lets you check for and fix these issues.

Comment: I've tried using `pavucontrol` and several other similar things, but the audio streams for some applications(ubuntu settings, chrome, firefox) are not showing up. (others, like teams, are working fine).